# I want to keep parts of Facebook & not others. Suggestions please

Tags: facebook

I have become disenchanted with facebook. People going there to rant & criticize is so very old. I would prefer to just be able to go there and read things from Smithsonian & women's health, etc.
I don't really know how best to do this. Just delete everyone from my friends list? Create a new account & close the current? I want to keep all of my photos and the hundreds of pages I like to read.
What can you suggest?

Comment: Do you know how to mute people?

Answer (score 1):

All of the options you have are definitely possibilities.

- Unfriend all of your friends ([Instructions](https://www.facebook.com/help/172936839431357))
- Unfollow all of your friends -- this means that they will still see anything you post and it will still list them as a friend in case you want to interact with them **but** they will no longer appear on your newsfeed/timeline ([Instructions](https://www.facebook.com/help/104941232944896))
- Deactivate your Facebook and look stuff up manually or create a new account ([Instructions - Deactivate](https://www.facebook.com/help/214376678584711)), ([Instructions - Create an account](https://www.facebook.com/help/345121355559712))